# Classic ASP returns the ID of the results in the URL

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

In a Classic ASP website and MSSQL database: When a search for data is completed the    URL displays the **ID** of the results. eg sitename/Display_Results.asp?cboService=**253**&cboRegion=**588**.  Where is the script or code that determines the return of the ID, is it in the page code or database stored procedures?  I want to display the description of the Id in the URL.

```
   <%@ language="vbscript" codepage="1252"%>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

   <%
   sRoot = ""`





   Function alert(msg,where)
   %> 
   alert('<%="Message = "&msg&"\nWhere = "&where%>') <% end function

   fFunction Ceiling(byval n) Dim iTmp, bErr

   on error resume next
    n = cdbl(n)
    if err then bErr = true
    on error goto 0

    if bErr then Err.Raise 5000, "Ceiling Function", _
    "Input must be convertible to a sub-type of double"

    f = Floor(n)
     if f = n then
    Ceiling = n
    Exit Function
     End If

     Ceiling = cInt(f + 1)
        End Function
        %>


        <html>

        <head>

         <!--#include file="includes/scripts/Includes.asp"-->

        <%
    Call WriteServiceMetaData(objConn, strConn)
        %>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/javascript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/pngfix.mod.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function showborder(idnew,argsnew){

    var idnew = idnew;
        var argsnew = argsnew;
    if(argsnew == "on"){
    document.getElementById(idnew).style.border='2px solid #759fb9';
     }
    else{
    document.getElementById(idnew).style.border='';
    }

        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showpng(idnew,argsnew){
    var idnew = idnew;
    var argsnew = argsnew;
    if(argsnew == "on"){
    document.getElementById(idnew).style.visibility='';
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById(idnew).style.visibility='hidden';
     }

        }
        </script>


         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=sRoot%>css/universal.css">
         </head>
         <%
     Dim maxResults
     Dim DRCountry_ID, Country_Variable
     Dim DRCounty_ID, County_Variable
     Dim DRLocation, Location_Variable
     Dim DRType_ID, DRType_ID_Array, Type_Variable, cType_Variable
     Dim End_request, LUXSQL
     Dim Query, Query_Result
     Dim Page_Num, HOTSQL, HOTOFFER, Text, DRTube_ID, DRPrice_Min, DRPrice_Max,    Tube_Variable, DRPrice, Price_Variable
      Dim lCityID, lCountyID, lCountryID

     set objRS = objConn.execute ("General_Admin_List")
     maxResults = objRS("Num_Results")
     objRS.Close
     set objRS = nothing
     'on error resume next
     'Page_Num= clng(Request.QueryString("Page_Num"))
     'if err.number <> 0 then
    'Page_Num = 0
      'end if
      'on error goto 0
          if strcomp(Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD"), "POST", 1) = 0 then

      on error resume next
      if len(trim(Request.Form("HotOffer"))) > 0 then
    iHotOffer = 1
      else
    iHotOffer = 0
       end if




        on error resume next
       'Turn off error handling
        company = trim(request.Form("company"))
        if company = "Enter Name" then
    company = ""
       end if
      if err.number <> 0 then
      'If there is an error then the requested input is not a number
    company = "null"
       end if
       err.clear
      'Turn error handling back on
       on error goto 0


       lCountyID = clng(trim(Request.Form("cboRegion")))
       if err.number <> 0 then
    lCountyID = 0
       end if
       err.clear

       lCountryID = clng(trim(Request.Form("cboCountry")))
       if err.number <> 0 then
    lCountryID = 0
        end if
        err.clear

        lFeatureID = clng(trim(Request.Form("cboFeature")))
        if err.number <> 0 then
    lFeatureID = 0
        end if
        err.clear

        lServiceID = clng(Request.Form("cboService"))
        if err.number <> 0 or lServiceID < 1 then
    lServiceID = 0
        else        
    session("SearchServiceID") = lServiceID

        end if
         err.clear

        lCityID = clng(Request.Form("cboCity"))
        if err.number <> 0 or lCityID < 1 then
    lCityID = 0
        end if


        sTypes = trim(Request.Form("asfTypes"))
        session("searchTypes") = sTypes
        on error goto 0
            else



        on error resume next
       'Turn off error handling
        company = trim(request.QueryString("company"))
        if company = "Enter Name" then
    company = ""
        end if
        if err.number <> 0 then
        'If there is an error then the requested input is not a number
    company = "null"
        end if
        err.clear
      'Turn error handling back on
       on error goto 0

        on error resume next
        if len(trim(Request.QueryString("HotOffer"))) > 0 then
    iHotOffer = 1
        else
    iHotOffer = 0
        end if

        lCountyID = clng(trim(Request.QueryString("cboRegion")))
        if err.number <> 0 then
    lCountyID = 0
        end if
         err.clear
        lCountryID = clng(trim(Request.QueryString("cboCountry")))
        if err.number <> 0 then
    lCountryID = 0
        end if
        err.clear

        lFeatureID = clng(trim(Request.QueryString("cboFeature")))
        if err.number <> 0 then
    lFeatureID = 0
        end if
         err.clear

         lServiceID = clng(Request.QueryString("cboService"))

        if err.number <> 0 or lServiceID < 1 then
    lServiceID = 0
         else
    session("SearchServiceID") = lServiceID

        end if
        err.clear

        if request.QueryString("asfFeatures") <> "" then
    lFeatureID = clng(Request.QueryString("asfFeatures"))
    if err.number <> 0 or lFeatureID < 1 then
        lFeatureID = 0
    end if
    err.clear
        end if

         lCityID = clng(Request.QueryString("CityID"))
         if err.number <> 0 or lCityID < 1 then
    lCityID = 0
        end if

        sTypes = trim(Request.QueryString("asfTypes"))
        'Response.Write(sTypes)
        session("searchTypes") = sTypes
         on error goto 0


             end if


            if lCityID = 0 then
         sCity = trim(Request.QueryString("City"))
         if len(sCity) = 0 then
    lCityID = 0
        else
    set objRS = objConn.execute ("City_Lookup '" & Replace(sCity, "'", "''") & "'")
     if objRS.EOF then
        lCityID = 999999
     else
        lCityID = objRS("City_ID")
        lCountyID = objRS("County_ID")
        lCountryID = objRS("Country_ID")
     end if
     objRS.Close
     set objRS = nothing
         end if
             end if
            'This below was commented out, seems to do nothing
        ' Not using location finder just yet
         dim sURL
          sURL = "Select_Location.asp?location=" &   Server.URLEncode(trim(Request.QueryString("SLocation"))) & "&Search=" & Request.QueryString("Search")
          sURL = sURL & "&Service=" & lServiceID
          sURL = sURL & "&Types=" & sTypes
         DRLocation = replace(trim(Request.QueryString("SLocation")), "'", "''")
        if len(DRLocation) > 0 then ' and lCountryID = 0 then
    set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRS.CursorLocation = 3
    objRS.Open "City_Lookup '" & DRLocation & "'," & lCountyID & ", " & lCountryID, objConn
      if objRS.RecordCount > 1 then
        objRS.Close
        objConn.close
        response.Redirect(sURL)
      end if
      if not objRS.eof then
        lCityID = clng(objRS("City_ID"))
        lCountyID = clng(objRS("County_ID"))
        else
        objRS.Close
        objRS.Open "County_Lookup '" & DRLocation & "', " & lCountryID, objConn
          if objRS.RecordCount > 1 then
            objRS.Close
            objConn.close
            response.Redirect(sURL)
         end if
         if not objRS.eof then
            lCountyID = clng(objRS("County_ID"))
         else
            objRS.Close
            objConn.close
            response.Redirect(sURL)
         end if
              end if


        objRS.Close
         set objRS = nothing
         end if
    'This above was commented out, seems to do nothing
      dim lSearchID
      lSearchID = 0

       if len(sTypes) > 0 then
        Application.Lock()
        if Application("LSG_SearchID") = "" then
            lSearchID = 1
        else
            lSearchID = clng(Application("LSG_SearchID")) + 1
        end if
        Application("LSG_SearchID") = lSearchID
        Application.UnLock()
        objConn.execute "Value_Splitter '" & sTypes & "', ',', " & lSearchID
    end if

    objConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    set objComm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    set objComm.ActiveConnection = objConn
    objComm.CommandText = "Search"
    objComm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@City_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@County_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Country_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Service_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Search_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Feature_ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Specialist_Area", adBoolean, adParamInput, , iHotOffer)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@ResultCount", adInteger, adParamOutput)
    objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter ("@Company", adVarchar, adParamInput, 255)

    if lCountryID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@Country_ID") = lCountryID
    end if
    if lCountyID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@County_ID") = lCountyID
    end if
    if lCityID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@City_ID") = lCityID
    end if
    if lServiceID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@Service_ID") = lServiceID
    end if
    if lFeatureID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@Feature_ID") = lFeatureID
    end if
    if lSearchID > 0 then
        objComm.Parameters("@Search_ID") = lSearchID
    end if

    if company = "null" then
        objComm.Parameters("@Company") = null
    else
        objComm.Parameters("@Company") = company
    end if

    'Query = "Search " & paramCity & ", " & paramCounty & ", " & paramCountry
'end if

        'response.End()
        'Set Query_Result = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        'Response.Write("Query"&Query)
         set Query_Result = objComm.Execute()
        lResultCount = objComm.Parameters("@ResultCount").value
         lSearchCity = lCityID



        if lServiceID > 0 then

        SELECT_SQL = "Service_Get "& lServiceID
    Set SELECT_SQL_RESULT = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        SELECT_SQL_RESULT.Open SELECT_SQL, ObjConn
    do while not SELECT_SQL_RESULT.eof
    service = SELECT_SQL_RESULT("service")
    service_description = SELECT_SQL_RESULT("Service_Description")
        SELECT_SQL_RESULT.MoveNext
    Loop
        SELECT_SQL_RESULT.Close
        end if              


            'Get city (set email location) from search and put into cookie
         if Request.QueryString("CityID") > 0 Then
    GetCity = "getCity "&Request.QueryString("CityID")
    Set GetCity_Result = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    GetCity_Result.Open GetCity, ObjConn
    if not GetCity_Result.eof then
        emailCity = GetCity_Result("City")
    end if  
    Response.Cookies("LSG")("Location") = emailCity
    Response.Cookies("LSG").Expires= DateAdd("d", Date(), 365)
       end if
            %>
            <%
            Dim SELECT_SQL, SELECT_SQL_RESULT
            Dim Top_PAGECONTENT_Title, Top_PAGECONTENT_Content
            Dim Bottom_PAGECONTENT_Title, Bottom_PAGECONTENT_Content

            Dim page_name, url,sPath
            sPath=""
            url = request.ServerVariables("URL")
            page_name = right(url, len(url) - instrrev(url, "/"))

            SELECT_SQL = "Page_Content_Get '"& page_name &"'"
            Set SELECT_SQL_RESULT = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            SELECT_SQL_RESULT.Open SELECT_SQL, ObjConn

            do while not SELECT_SQL_RESULT.eof
        If SELECT_SQL_RESULT("Position") = "Page Top" then
    Top_PAGECONTENT_Title = SELECT_SQL_RESULT("Title")
    Top_PAGECONTENT_Content = SELECT_SQL_RESULT("Content")
    Top_PAGECONTENT_Content = Replace(Top_PAGECONTENT_Content, vbcrlf, "<br>")
        end if
        SELECT_SQL_RESULT.MoveNext
            Loop
            SELECT_SQL_RESULT.Close
             %>


               <body>
           <div class="SiteContainer">
           <!--#include file="includes/content/banner_rotator.asp"-->
       <div class="LeftSiteContainer">  
        <!--#include file="includes/content/hdg_left.asp"-->
        <!--#include file="includes/content/hdg_Header2.asp"-->
        <div class="indexMainContainer">
            <div id="mainLeftContent">

                <div class="MainContent">                   

                    <%                          
                        if service = "" then
                            service = "Boat and Yacht products and services"
                        end if
                        if emailcity = "" then
                            emailcity = "Boat Chandlers Guide"
                        end if
                    %>
            <%If not Query_Result.EOF Then%>
                        <span style="color:#1A59CD;"><h1><%=service%></h1></span>   
                        <span style="color:#1A59CD;"><h2><%=Service_Description%></h2></span>
                        <div style="color:#666666; float:left; padding-top:8px;">Your search returned <span style="color:#1A59CD; font-weight:bold;"><%=lResultCount%></span> result<%if lResultCount > 1 then response.write "s" end if%> for <!--<%=emailcity%> to--> <%=service%> </div>     
                        <div style="clear:both;">   </div>&nbsp;                                                
                        <!--<h2><%=emailcity%> search results for <%=service%></h2>-->
                    <% else %>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>&nbsp;
                        <span style="color:#1A59CD;"><h1><%=emailcity%> <%=service%></h1></span>
                            <div class="search_no_results">                          
                          <strong>Sorry, there are currently no <%=service%> featured on <%=emailcity%> at this time.</strong>
                        </div>
                    <% End If %>
                <%If not Query_Result.EOF Then
                    numResults = maxResults 'The Number of Results to Display on each page                      
                    count = lResultCount                        
                    dim Number_array, Total_Pages
                    Number_Array = split(((count-1) / numResults),".")                      
                    Total_Pages = count \ numResults                            
                    if count mod numResults > 0 then
                        Total_Pages = Total_Pages + 1
                    end if
                    %>                      
                <%end if

                If Query_Result.EOF Then%>
                    <div class="search_no_results">
                      <strong>Sorry, no results were found that match your search criteria.</strong>
                    </div>
                <% End If

                Dim count, strt, endd, numResults, tr_count
                tr_count = 0
                '-----------------------------------------------'
                ' Set the Number of the first record to display '
                '-----------------------------------------------'
                if not Query_Result.eof then
                    strt = cint(Request.queryString("results"))
                    if (strt = null) OR (strt <= 0) then
                        strt = 1
                    end if
                    endd = strt + numResults-1
                    if numresults = 1 then
                        Page_Num = strt
                    else

                        Page_Num = strt \ numresults
                        Page_Num = Page_Num + 1
                    end if
                end if
                count = 1

                PageEnd = Page_Num * numResults
                PageStart = PageEnd - 20    
                if PageEnd > lResultCount then
                    pageEnd = lResultCount                                  
                end if  

                if request.QueryString("st") = "" then
                    CurrentPageNumber = 1
                else
                    CurrentPageNumber = request.QueryString("st") 
                end if

                'How many on first number
                FirstNum = numResults * (CurrentPagenumber - 1) - (numResults -1)                               
                if clng(CurrentPageNumber) < clng(Total_Pages) then                                             
                    if clng(Total_Pages - 1) = clng(CurrentPageNumber) then
                        high = CurrentPageNumber + 1
                    else
                        high = CurrentPageNumber + 2
                    end if                  
                end if

                'How many on last number
                LastNum = numResults * (CurrentPagenumber + 1) - (numResults-1)                                             
                LastCount =  ((Total_Pages - 1) * numResults) + 1   

                if lResultCount > 0 then%>
                    <DIV class="displayResultsPageNumberContainer">                                         
                        <div class="displayResultsPrevious">                                
                            <% if Page_Num > 1 then %>
                                <A id="Page<%=PageNumber%>" style="color:#6b98b4;" href="Display_Results.asp?cboCountry=<%=lCountryID%>&cboFeature=<%=request.QueryString("cboFeature")%>&cboRegion=<%=lCountyID%>&cboService=<%=lServiceID%>&asfTypes=<%=sTypes%>&CityID=<%=lSearchCity%>&asfFeatures=<%=lFeatureID%><%if iHotOffer > 0 then response.Write("&HotOffer=Y") end if%>&results=<%=FirstNum%>&st=<%=CurrentPagenumber-1%>"><<Previous</A>          
                            <% else %>
                                &nbsp;                              
                            <% end if %>
                        </div>

                        <% if cint(Page_Num) < cint(Total_Pages) then 
                            %>                                  
                            <div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><A style="color:#6b98b4;" id="Page<%=PageNumber%>" href="Display_Results.asp?cboCountry=<%=lCountryID%>&cboFeature=<%=request.QueryString("cboFeature")%>&cboRegion=<%=lCountyID%>&cboService=<%=lServiceID%>&asfTypes=<%=sTypes%>&CityID=<%=lSearchCity%>&asfFeatures=<%=lFeatureID%><%if iHotOffer > 0 then response.Write("&HotOffer=Y") end if%>&st=<%=CurrentPagenumber+1%>&results=<%=LastNum%>">Next >></a></div>
                        <% end if %>            
                    </DIV>
                <%end if


                Do Until Query_Result.EOF or count > endd
                    if (count >= strt) AND (count <= endd) then
                        Image_Query = "Advert_Images_Get "&Query_Result("Advert_ID")
                        Set Image_Query_Result = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                        Image_Query_Result.Open Image_Query, ObjConn
                        if not Image_Query_Result.eof then
                            ImgThumb = replace(Image_Query_Result("Image_Name"),".jpg","_db_mid.jpg")

                        else
                            ImgThumb = "1pxSpacer.gif"
                        end if

                        %>
                        <div class="search_result_advert">
                            <% newCity = replace(Query_Result("City"),",","_") %>
                            <div class="search_result_advert_img">
                                <div><a title="View Advert - <%=Query_Result("Title")%>" href="<%=getFilename(newCity, Query_Result("Title"), Query_Result("Advert_ID"))%>"><img  src="adverts_pics/<%=ImgThumb%>" alt="<%=Query_Result("Title")%>" border="0" /></a></div>                             
                            </div>
                            <div class="search_result_advert_details">
                                <div style="float:right;"><a style="color:#6b98b4;" title="View Advert - <%=Query_Result("Title")%>" href="<%=getFilename(newCity, Query_Result("Title"), Query_Result("Advert_ID"))%>">More Info</a></div>
                                <h3><a id="Result<%=Query_Result("Advert_ID")%>" title="View Advert - <%=Query_Result("Title")%>" href="<%=getFilename(newCity, Query_Result("Title"), Query_Result("Advert_ID"))%>"><%=ucase(TruncateString(Query_Result("Title"),30))%></a></h3>                                                      
                                <div style="margin-top:5px;"><%=TruncateString(Query_Result("Description"), 320)%></div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top:10px; height:5px;"></div>
                        <%
                    end if
                    count = count + 1
                    Query_Result.MoveNext
                Loop


                %>

                <%if lResultCount > 0 then%>
                    <DIV class="displayResultsPageNumberContainer">                                         
                        <div class="displayResultsPrevious">                                
                            <% if Page_Num > 1 then %>
                                <A style="color:#6b98b4;" id="Page<%=PageNumber%>" href="Display_Results.asp?cboCountry=<%=lCountryID%>&cboFeature=<%=request.QueryString("cboFeature")%>&cboRegion=<%=lCountyID%>&cboService=<%=lServiceID%>&asfTypes=<%=sTypes%>&CityID=<%=lSearchCity%>&asfFeatures=<%=lFeatureID%><%if iHotOffer > 0 then response.Write("&HotOffer=Y") end if%>&results=<%=FirstNum%>&st=<%=CurrentPagenumber-1%>"><< Previous</A>             
                            <% else %>
                                &nbsp;                          
                            <% end if %>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="displayResultsPageNumber">Displaying <b><%=PageStart%> - <%=PageEnd%> of <%=lResultCount%> Search Results for </b></div>-->
                        <% if cint(Page_Num) < cint(Total_Pages) then 
                            %>                                  
                            <div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><A style="color:#6b98b4;" id="Page<%=PageNumber%>" href="Display_Results.asp?cboCountry=<%=lCountryID%>&cboFeature=<%=request.QueryString("cboFeature")%>&cboRegion=<%=lCountyID%>&cboService=<%=lServiceID%>&asfTypes=<%=sTypes%>&CityID=<%=lSearchCity%>&asfFeatures=<%=lFeatureID%><%if iHotOffer > 0 then response.Write("&HotOffer=Y") end if%>&st=<%=CurrentPagenumber+1%>&results=<%=LastNum%>">Next >></a></div>
                        <% end if %>            
                    </DIV>
                <%end if%>  

                <br/>
                <br/>
                <div class="advanced_bg">
                    <div style="float:left;"><img src="images/img_advanced.jpg" alt="Advanced Search"/></div>
                    <div id="advanced_title">  <%=Top_PAGECONTENT_Title%></div>
                    <%=Top_PAGECONTENT_Content%>
                </div>      

            </div>
            <%
            '<!--#include file="includes/content/hdg_right.asp"-->  
            %>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div id="footer"><!--#include file="includes/content/hdg_Footer.asp"-->    </div>
</div>  
                   </body>
                       </html>
                       <!--#include file="includes/scripts/DatabaseConnectClose.asp"-->
```

Comment: How do I reply to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

without you showing the code, it would be difficult to determine exactly what is going on, but my best guess would that your form method is set to "get" and not "post".

it is for this reason all these value pairs are displaying in the URL.
In addition, the ID you are wanting to be there as well, is this perhaps currently in a hidden field??

Comment: Thanks Guru, this is the code from between the head tags in "Display_result.asp" Note some of the code may not be relevant as I inherited this website.

Comment: Hi Guru, I've tried but this comment box won't let me paste that much text??

Comment: how about everything between the FORM tags?

Comment: Hi Guru, I've updated my question above, thanks for your patience.